плоский круг на css
Как в css сделать вот такой плоский круг c переливающимся градиентом


это называется эллипс. 2. дубликаты, вероятно, где-то здесь


Хорошо спасибо но как сделать чтобы он переливался градиентом (любыми цветами)? Этот эллипс я уже сама сделала

это уже совершенно другой вопрос, вообще никак с первым не связанный. и эти два вопроса надо было задавать отдельно.

блин вот почему от этого сайта никакой пользы. Смысл тут задавать вопросы если все только просто умничают а по делу никогда не отвечают

А вы будьте добры, прочитайте правила, прежде чем задать самый умный вопрос на этом свете. Уверяю, не будем умничать.

прошу вас ознакомиться с туром, чтоб понять работу ru.SO => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour //так же как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

чтобы вычислить цвет градиента, можно воспользоваться готовым генератором цветов

чтоб сделать овальную форму // еще пример с пояснениями
Чтобы превратить прямоугольник в эллипс, установим для свойства border-radius высокое значение (от 50% до 100%). Это свойство отвечает за округление углов фигуры. Высота прямоугольника станет малой осью эллипса, а ширина — большой осью.


.oval {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,70,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<div class="oval"></div>



